# Java: ensure web application open only in one browser tab

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

What is the best approach to ensure that a specific page (assume a single-page Web application) is open only in one browser tab?

Assume the Java Web app has authentication, i.e. user has to sign in (so we can identify which page is being viewed by which user via Java Session API).

The intention is that if another tab is opened for the same URL, the user will be redirected to a static page that tells him he has the application open somewhere else (another tab).

My current approach fails to work for tabs in the same browser, since `JSESSIONID` is stored in cookies, that are available for all browser's tabs.

Comment: I have a single-page application, a "rich client". I need to constrain it to be open only in one tab, as having it open in different tabs will lead to more complexity.

Comment: Let me guess, you have shared session causing issues when two browsers are opening your app?

Comment: @ChinBoon That is another way to look at this problem.

Comment: Another way to deal with this is to use a PhaseListener and record the current page and then send the user to that page if he is on a different one. That way every tab would be forced to be on the same page it also disables Browser Navigation (which is what i use it for mainly).

Comment: @Stefan: how exactly did you conclude that OP is using JSF? There isn't any indication in the whole question, let alone in OP's post history, that OP is using JSF.

Comment: @BalusC I did not conclude that. Thats why i did not post it as an answer. Its an option if you are willing to go JSF (which is probably not the case since the OP didnt respond to the comment) or one could implement a similar solution without JSF. I.e. reset to the 'current' Page in a ServletFilter.

Comment: @Stefan No JSF, thanks. What does *OP* stand for? Didn't know you were referring to the "author".

Comment: @Josvic Zammit http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op . The PhaseListener is JSF specific but the strategy i described above could most likely be implemented using a ServletFilter

Comment: @Stefan Thanks; I don't understand what you propose and how I would do it as a ServletFilter for a Single-page app (rich JavaScript client). I just serve 1 html file throughout the whole app's lifecycle.

Comment: @Josvic Zammit Ah nevermind i totally missed the single page part.

Comment: @Stefan No prob, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your current use case is this:

1. The user opens a browser tab, loads your application page and logs in.

The user then opens a second browser tab, loads your application page and is already logged in (because the browser has the same session cookies for all tabs or windows).

And you want to restrict the user so that if when they load the second tab, the instead see a warning message saying: You have already logged into this site elsewhere, please use that window, or if you no longer have that window open, click here to logout and log back in again.

Most solutions will involve keeping a one time token for the instance of the application along with the session. If your application loads up in a single page and presents the user with a login box then when the user logs in you could send the one time token, store it in a javascript variable and send it with all server requests.
If the user then loads up the application in a new tab, they request their initial data and the server can generate a response saying that the token is not present and they need to logout, close the window or switch to the already logged in window.

So the answer is baically that you want to store a random string in your session on the server, serve it to the user on login and check that every request has it otherwise bounce them to a logout page. And in the javascript of the web client, store that token and send it with every request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an asynchron call to the backend (keyword: long time polling) and send single bytes through it to keep it alive. As long as it is alive, the tab is open. If a second call comes in you can test on that.

Comment: why the downvote? This might not be a 'nice' solution, but it solves the problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote your solution, someone else did, and should justify why. Since, as you said, it's not an elegant one (it may give rise to other issues) I will try it only as last resort. Right now I'm still searching.