# How to detect if user has already opened an url and redirect to same if already opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, client-side

Can anyone please tell me how can I detect if user has already opened the link/url tab and is it possible to redirect a link to a active browser tab if the url is already opened?

Eg: User clicks on the link and js code will open a new tab in browser.Now if user again clicks on the link I want him to redirect to the active session instead of opening a new tab.

I read the below post but unable to implement my logic according to them:

[Java: ensure web application open only in one browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652861/java-ensure-web-application-open-only-in-one-browser-tab)
[Possible to detect if a user has multiple tabs of your site open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038629/possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-multiple-tabs-of-your-site-open)

I am using simple **window.open(url)** to open my url in new tab.

Thanks....

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would be a privacy violation. Anyway, are those links from the same domain?

Comment: Yes they are for same domain and we are performing SSO to validate so security violation is not a concern.

Comment: I said privacy, not security :) I thought you needed to check the client's browser history to perform your task. That's not allowed (anymore).

Comment: oh! yea, sorry about that. But the below solutions worked well for me.I am a newbee in UI, still learning all tips and tricks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you give a name to the opened window it will reopen the same the second time

```
    window.open(url,"mypopup");
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Any possibility that the above will not refresh/reload the url? Right now the above is working well but every time it reloads the window which my client don't want.

Comment: window.open returns a window object. You could use this to know when window is already opened and focus on it instead of reloading see example: http://jsfiddle.net/DfpG5/

Answer (score 0):

use the target/window name in javascript do that

```
window.open(yoururl, youruniquewindowname)
```

example

```
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/", "stack_unique_123")
```

if a window with stack_unique_123, is already open, the "https://stackoverflow.com/" will be reload in that window, preventing a new one to be open.