# Can a new page have a target="" name if not opened with a target attribute?

Tags: html

I want to have two pages that link to each other but stay open unless the user closes them. I know I can say `target="first"` and `target="second"` but is there any way of getting the first page to have the target name of "first" without clicking on a link to open it?

Usage:

- Open page "first" by typing the address (or getting link from search engine, etc.)
- Click on a link to second page - page "second" opens in a new tab
- Click on a link in the second page - the link opens in the "first" tab

At the moment I end up with two copies of page "first":

1. Name: none, Content: first page
2. Name: "second", Content: second page
3. Name: "first", Content: first page

I want to reuse page 1 instead of opening page 3.

Is this possible? How? Can this be done with any number of pages (i.e. not relying on parent to work)?

Comment: Why do you need each page to open in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript function

```
window.open(url,"mypopup");
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DfpG5/

Refer this answer :
[How to detect if user has already opened an url and redirect to same if already opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346114/how-to-detect-if-user-has-already-opened-an-url-and-redirect-to-same-if-already)

Comment: Isn't that effectively the same as clicking on a link with `target="mypopup"`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what I want:

target.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Target</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (document.parentWindow.name == "") {
        document.parentWindow.name = "foobar";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="target2.html" target="barfoo">Second page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

target2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Target 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (document.parentWindow.name == "") {
        document.parentWindow.name = "barfoo";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="target.html" target="foobar">First page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I haven't tested it in many browsers yet so I don't know how compatible it is.

Comment: It appears that `window` is more compatible than `document.parentWindow`