# Restrict Vue.js Application To Only One Browser Tab

Tags: javascript, browser, vue.js, single-page-application

#### Background:

I'm developing a SPA using Vue.js which involves realtime communications using user's microphone and speaker.

Because of these RTC functionalities, having the application open in more than one browser tab may cause problems (e.g. echos).

#### Question:

How can I restrict the number of simultaneously open browser tabs of the application (i.e. application instances) to just one?

*I'm not sure if the fact that I'm using Vue.js is relevant here but it probably worths mentioning.*

#### Notes:

I've already read [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149542/3173442) to the following question: [Java: ensure web application open only in one browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652861/java-ensure-web-application-open-only-in-one-browser-tab)

It involves having some session data stored on the server but **I'd like to keep my server-side code stateless.**
So I want to find a solution that can be implemented **completely on the client-side.**

I know that there probably is not a solution to this problem across different browsers on a machine which doesn't involve server-side coding. I'd like to know the options for limiting the number of open instances per browser though.

Comment: I'd probably look into having the communication hub act as a gatekeeper.

Comment: A "production" example of this that comes to my mind is Telegram Web, you can check the specific part of its code [here](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/blob/a6ea6288d0be6bab28dd412fac1c66244fee7ba1/app/js/lib/mtproto_wrapper.js#L746-#L844)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer but I am thinking you could accomplish this using local storage and in your case specifically the nice [vue-ls](https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-ls) module.  The JsFiddle provided shows how to share information across tabs -- extending this so that if you get the ls$ value and it exists (say keep a track of open tabs?) then close down or show a dialog box, etc.